Using C# Winforms with the Windows 10 and PowerShell command line make the application waiting forever. no errors just hanging. How to fix?
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                button1.Enabled = false;

                await RunPowerShellAsync();
                await RunFfmpegAsync();
                button1.Enabled = true;
                MessageBox.Show("GIF creation complete!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private Task RunPowerShellAsync()
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                string powershellScript = "Get-ChildItem 'D:\\New folder (76)\\Image*.png' | ForEach-Object { \"file '$($_.FullName)'\" } > image_list.txt";
                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "powershell.exe",
                    Arguments = $"-Command \"{powershellScript}\"",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true
                };

                using (Process process = new Process { StartInfo = psi })
                {
                    process.Start();
                    process.WaitForExit();
                }
            });
        }

It's getting to the WaitForExit, but then after that line, nothing happens - it never finishes.

Why are you using a new process instead of a runspace?

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76398401/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/73982594/10024425

"it never finishes" because WaitForExit waits for powershell to close.
Adding exit to the command, like:
Get-ChildItem 'D:\\New folder (76)\\Image*.png' | ForEach-Object { \"file '$($_.FullName)'\" } > image_list.txt; exit

should do that
